# Promise returned in function argument where a void return was expected, passportjs

Tags: typescript, mongoose, passport.js

I'm currently trying to implement a basic google uauth2 with passport.js, this is the function I'm trying to rewrite/adapt to mongoose

```
  function verify(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
    db.get('SELECT * FROM federated_credentials WHERE provider = ? AND subject = ?', [
      'https://accounts.google.com',
      profile.id
    ], function(err, cred) {
      if (err) { return cb(err); }
      
      if (!cred) {
        // The account at Google has not logged in to this app before.  Create a
        // new user record and associate it with the Google account.
        db.run('INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES (?)', [
          profile.displayName
        ], function(err) {
          if (err) { return cb(err); }
          
          var id = this.lastID;
          db.run('INSERT INTO federated_credentials (user_id, provider, subject) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', [
            id,
            'https://accounts.google.com',
            profile.id
          ], function(err) {
            if (err) { return cb(err); }
            
            var user = {
              id: id,
              name: profile.displayName
            };
            return cb(null, user);
          });
        });
      } else {
        // The account at Google has previously logged in to the app.  Get the
        // user record associated with the Google account and log the user in.
        db.get('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?', [ cred.user_id ], function(err, user) {
          if (err) { return cb(err); }
          if (!user) { return cb(null, false); }
          return cb(null, user);
        });
      }
    });
```

And this is what I rewrote:

```
import passport from "passport";
import { Strategy as GoogleStrategy } from "passport-google-oauth20";
import User from "./models/User";
import FederatedCredentials from "./models/FederatedCredentials";

async function verify(_accessToken, _refreshToken, profile, cb) {
  let user = null;
  try {
    const result = await FederatedCredentials.findOne({
      provider: "https://accounts.google.com",
      subject: profile.id,
    }).exec();
    if (result instanceof Error) {
      cb(result);
      return;
    } else if (result === undefined || result === null) {
      {
        try {
          user = await User.create({
            username: profile.displayName,
            email: profile.emails![0].value,
          });
          await user.save();
        } catch (err) {
          return cb(err as Error);
        }
      }
      if (user) {
        try {
          const fc = await FederatedCredentials.create({
            userId: user._id,
            provider: "https://accounts.google.com",
            subject: profile.id,
          });
          await fc.save();
        } catch (err) {
          return cb(err as Error);
        }
      } else {
        cb(null, user);
        return;
      }
    } else {
      try {
        const userToFind = await User.findById(result.userId).exec();
        if (userToFind instanceof Error) return cb(userToFind);
        else if (!userToFind) return cb(null, false);
        else return cb(null, userToFind);
      } catch (err) {
        return cb(err as Error);
      }
    }
  } catch (err) {
    return cb(err as Error);
  }
},
```

I'm getting the "Promise returned in function argument where a void return was expected", tried looking up the explanation of the error online but didn't get it. What am I doing wrong?